# jQuery masonry multiple ajax call issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I'm experiencing an issue using the jQuery Masonry Plugin with an ajax call.

I have a filter function which is getting some pretty standard html content from the server (divs, no images):

```
var searchResults   = $('div#results');

function filter() {

    var text        = 'text';
    var orderby     = 'order';
    var source      = 'source';
    var media       = 'media';
    var format      = 'format';
    var tags        = 'tags';

    var fetchUrl    = '/search/results/ ' + text + '/' + orderby + '/' + source + '/' + media + '/' + format + '/' + tags;


    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: fetchUrl,
            cache: false,
            data: "after=000000",
            success: function(data){ 

                searchResults.html(data);

                $('#results').masonry({
                  columnWidth: 360, 
                  itemSelector: '.related' 
                });
            }
        });

}
```

This is then called on page load like so:

```
if (searchResults.length > 0) {

    filter();

}
```

This is all working as expected. However, when I try and call `filter()` from a click, it's getting the content fine but masonry isn't formatting it:

```
$('nav#view-types a#grid, nav#view-types a#list').click(function() {

    filter();

    return false;

});
```

As I'm calling masonry in the Ajax success function and it's working on the first run, I can't really see what the issue could be... anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell masonry to "refire" after the ajax load finishes:

example:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("Ajax finished"); //remove this if you want, useful for debugging
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#content').masonry({
       columnWidth: 260, //change this accordingly
       itemSelector: '.item'
      });
    });
});
```

Masonry has a .reload() but I found it didnt really work well unless you were appending or prepending. To call it when completely changing the contents I had to do it like this.

Maybe a better solution here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#admin_content').masonry({
       columnWidth: 260,
       itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
       isAnimated:true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 500,
                    easing:'swing',
                    queue :false
               }
      });
    });
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#admin_content').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

Comment: THIS
$('#admin_content').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
works like a charm

Comment: OMG. I was trying to make masonry work with history pushState, and finally, after 2-3 days i found a answer! TY!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $('#results').masonry('reload') after you have appended your items.